# what is the best way to store a lot of markers in database?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, google-maps, database-design

I want to create a web site using google maps, php, mysql and javascript where users can leave a marker on a map with message so that another users will be able to see thismarker on their map. And all of this in a real time.

I suppose that amount of markers will be huge, so i decided to store markers in database using tiles:

You can see picture explaining this over here

http://kunuk.wordpress.com/2011/11/05/google-map-server-side-clustering-with-asp-net/

http://www.soak.co.uk/blog/server-side-map-marker-clustering/

So for example, at the beginning the coordinates of client viewport are determined and  the tiles to be loaded from the server are calculated, after that the server determine the markers that are whithin the requested tiles and sends them to the client.

My question is what is the best way to organise the database that will store markers by tiles?

Can smn show an example or there is already a standart solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are over-complicating this. If the only thing you are storing is the markers (lat & lon), then a single database table will do.

Something like:

- id
- user_id
- tile_id
- lat
- lon
- message

Comment: But the server is requested a certain tiles from client, and therefore markers need to be stored using tiles.

Comment: That's why he is suggesting `tile_id` as a field, no? So you can request markers by tiles that are on display.

Comment: The text on your soak.com link mentions that there is only one table being used. You have to calculate an ID for each tile on each zoom level using PHP, not in the database.

Comment: Yes, i saw title_id but imagine that i have 100 000 markers and a certain tiles were requested by user - to find these markers(from certain tiles) i will need to go through all this 100 000 markers.Is it a good idea to have a table for each tile?

Comment: You won't have to loop every marker, A simple `SELECT * FROM markers WHERE tile_id = x` won't take too long, spreading them across tables won't make things quicker.

Comment: Thnx. One more question: have you tried this implementation on your own? Will this method really increase the speed of whole system?

Comment: It will, but generating the virtual tiles is hard work. You would need to know the coords of each corner of the tiles so when you get a new marker you know which tile to assign it to.

Comment: Thx one more time. And the last one: have you seen any working examples of this method. I'm interested in php and js implementation of this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to work with a large amount of markers, definitely take a look at google fusion tables:

https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/

And you can read more about it here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers

Comment: Yes, i tried it out. But i don't want to use it, it has limitations.